# Unable to post question, but no error message shown

Tags: bug

I am unable to post my question on Stack Overflow. I am not getting any error but the page is remaining stand still.

I was able to post the same question on superuser.com. My question was related to Oracle Database and here is the superuser.com link: https://superuser.com/questions/1413895/error-while-getting-status-of-instane-and-database-in-oracle

Edit -

I tried to modify my question but it didn't work.
As suggested I have posted a screenshot -
[image]

Comment: Open the developer console of your browser and check the network tab to see if there are errors in there. I'm guessing some resource is blocked by for example a firewall.

Comment: I can see pop-up like "Is your question about programming? ...." I cannot see any network error.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the entire browser window?

Comment: I wanted to post on Stackoverflow because its more technical side rather discussion however since i was unable to post on stackoverflow I posted it on superuser.com ? I am pretty sure that question would be moved to stackoverflow or remain unanswered in superuser.com.

Comment: Press ctrl+alt+print screen when you are on the ask question page and the console window is open. Go to paint and paste that image and save it. Please upload it here. If you have a screen shot software, you can use that.

Comment: Did you hit submit to your question?

Comment: I don't know whats was the issue, it definitely was not network as I was able to post here but it got solved as I mentioned below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what was the issue but I did few refresh, copied my answer again and posted, first it was showing 90min error but I tried again with re-framing question and it worked.

Comment: That's good. You got the answer. Probably some internal server error was there.